# German vowel charts with phonetic accuracy

Tags: phonetics, german

German vowel charts used in the wikipedia article [Standard German phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_German_phonology) do not locate vowels with great details. For example German [e] is a bit higher than the IPA [e] (something like what is shown in [this vowel chart](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Positions-of-German-vowels-in-the-pronunciation-system-the-i-sound-Rausch-Rausch_fig1_280978405)) or tense vowel [e:] is not produced exactly in the same location of its allophone short vowel [e]. the wikipedia charts are phonemic oriented for example [e:] and [e] are grouped together as "e(:)"

Comment: I suggest getting a print article with a vowel chart, where vowel symbols can be more precisely located. IPA sketches are good for getting impressions of vowel positions.

Comment: Standard German arguably does not have an exactly defined pronunciation.

Comment: Oh, got it, you are talking about the allophonic use of [e] for /eː/ in unstressed syllables in Latinate words?

Comment: @sumelic. exactly